# Error messages not being displayed to user

Tags: php, html

Slowly learning php with much much more to go. Found myself at a point in the book I think is useful practice coding example. I want to check a users password for length and complexity. Yes, I understand there is much room for longer and more complex passwords. This problem is good enough for me to learn slowly. Requirements are exactly 9 characters and 1 @ sign. All other characters are allowed. Not sure why error messages are not being returned when password doesn't meet requirements. Any help is appreciated and know this is probably a beaten dead horse. Most of the other answers here are more complex than I want but will eventually get there. Please comment constructively...thanks!

```
<?php
       $pwd = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'password');
       $errmsg = "";

       //function with 2 parameters/one passed by reference
       function passVal($pwd) {
           $errmsg = null;
           if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*[@]){9}$/', $pwd)) {
                  $errmsg = "Password must contain exactly 9 characters and one @ sign.";
           }
           if (strlen($pwd == 9) && preg_match('/(?=.*[@])/', $pwd)) {
                 $errmsg = "Contains exactly 9 characters and there is at least one @ sign. Password is good";
           }
        return $errmsg;
      }
 ?>
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<header><h1>Password Check</h1></header>
<form action="" method="get">
<h3>Enter a password in the box.</h3><br>
<p>The password must be exactly 9 characters and include at least
one &#64 sign. All other characters are allowed.</p>
<p>Enter a password<input type="text" name="password"></p>
<p><button type="submit" formmethod="get" name="button">Check Password</button></p>
<p><?php echo $errmsg; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you calling the "passVal" function?

Comment: For one thing, you don't appear to be actually calling your passVal() function.

Comment: And you're not reading the submitted password from $_GET anywhere.

Comment: That conditional of yours is failing you also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the other answers given. Stating you never called the `passVal()` function.

Your conditional statement for `strlen()` is failing you.

```
if (strlen($pwd == 9) && preg_match('/(?=.*[@])/', $pwd))
```

and should read as, and wrapping `$pwd` inside brackets:

```
if ((strlen($pwd) == 9) && preg_match('/(?=.*[@])/', $pwd))
```

as per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php on the `strlen()` function.

- `strlen($str);`

So your `(strlen($pwd == 9)` will fail here.

You can therefore add and echo the function with the `$pwd` parameter:

```
echo passVal($pwd);
```

after

```
    return $errmsg;
}
```

Yet, using a conditional statement for it to check if it's set/not empty would be better.

***Sidenote edit:*** It appears that you did not close off the form, so if that is your actual code, you will need to add it `</form>`.

---

*Toying with the idea edit*.

You can also use a ternary operator in checking for both a conditional `empty()` and echoing the function inside the same line.

I.e.: `<p><?php  echo !empty($pwd) ? passVal($pwd) : ''; ?></p>` and defining two different messages assigned to `$errmsg` from both `$msg_bad` and `$msg_good`.

Here's a full rewrite:

```
<?php

$pwd = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'password');

$msg_bad = "<b>Password must contain exactly 9 characters and one @ sign.</b>";
$msg_good  = "Contains exactly 9 characters and there is at least one @ sign. Password is good";


//function with 2 parameters/one passed by reference
function passVal($pwd) {

global $msg_good, $msg_bad;

    $errmsg = null;


    if ((strlen($pwd) == 9) && preg_match('/(?=.*[@])/', $pwd)) {

        $errmsg = $msg_good;

    }

    else {

        $errmsg = $msg_bad;

    }

     return $errmsg;

}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<header><h1>Password Check</h1></header>

<form action="" method="get">
<h3>Enter a password in the box.</h3>
<p>The password must be exactly 9 characters and include at least
one &#64 sign. All other characters are allowed.</p>
<p>Enter a password<input type="text" name="password"></p>
<p><button type="submit" formmethod="get" name="button">Check Password</button></p>
</form>

<p><?php  echo !empty($pwd) ? passVal($pwd) : ''; ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is good explanation. It seems like I'm always missing a critical piece of syntax. Unfortunately unless at home my means for debugging are limited. I accepted this answer because my goal was to apply regex in this code and not do work around. Fixed my errors and now it is working. Thanks!

Comment: @allendks45 You're welcome, was glad to have been of help. I made a slight edit to my answer where I wasn't sure if your working code does contain the closing `</form>` tag or not. I have added that to my answer near the bottom, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below, I moved the $errmsg variable down and call the function to assign the returned value to it.

```
<?php
$pwd = $_GET['password'];

//function with 2 parameters/one passed by reference
function passVal($pwd) {
    $errmsg = null;

    if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*[@]){9}$/', $pwd)) {
        $errmsg = "Password must contain exactly 9 characters and one @ sign.";
        }

    if (strlen($pwd == 9) && preg_match('/(?=.*[@])/', $pwd)) {
         $errmsg = "Contains exactly 9 characters and there is at least one @ sign. Password is good";
}
    return $errmsg;
}

**$errmsg = passVal($pwd);**

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<header><h1>Password Check</h1></header>
<form action="" method="get">
<h3>Enter a password in the box.</h3><br>
<p>The password must be exactly 9 characters and include at least
one &#64 sign. All other characters are allowed.</p>
<p>Enter a password<input type="text" name="password"></p>
<p><button type="submit" formmethod="get" name="button">Check Password</button></p>
<p><?php echo $errmsg; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you never call the `passVal` function. You should be doing something like this:

```
if( ! empty( $_GET ) ) {
    $errmsg = passVal( $_GET['password'] );
}
```

A function isn't automatically called simply because you submit a form. In fact you should always check if a form has been submitted and then do the processing you need.

Ideally you should also separate your PHP logic from your HTML, but that's another topic entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the function plus there is no need for a function. Do this:

```
<?php
$pwd = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'password');
$errmsg = "";
//function with 2 parameters/one passed by reference

if ((count($pwd)<9) && (strpos($pwd, "@") == false)) {
    $errmsg = "Password must contain exactly 9 characters and one @ sign.";
    }
else {
     $errmsg = "Contains exactly 9 characters and there is at least one @sign. Password is good";
}



?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<header><h1>Password Check</h1></header>
<form action="" method="get">
<h3>Enter a password in the box.</h3><br>
<p>The password must be exactly 9 characters and include at least
one &#64 sign. All other characters are allowed.</p>
<p>Enter a password<input type="text" name="password"></p>
<p><button type="submit" formmethod="get" name="button">Check   Password</button></p>
<p><?php echo $errmsg; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```